# Crear un .bat o .reg para configurar un proxy en windows 10

Tags: windows, proxy

necesito un .bat que modifique el proxy y se aplique al momento de correrlo, un compañero genero un archivo de editar el registro de windows y efectivamente el proxy se modifica pero es como si solo se escribiera el proxy y no se le diera al boton de save ya que todo sigue igual.

El motivo de colocar el proxy es solucionar temporalmente una desconexion que tienen las pc de mi empresa hacia la web por una gpo que activaron en el server. Actualmente estan trabajando en una forma de corregir una brecha de seguridad que hubo y que halla conexiones seguras pero por el momento no esta funcionando y cada vez que alguien bloquea su pc o la reinicia pierde la configuracion del proxy, como son demasiadas personas llamando pensamos dejar un archivo .bat en el file server y que solo deban ejecutarlo y lo solucione pero el editor de registro que hizo nuestro compañero no esta funcionando les dejo el codigo del editor de registro:

```html
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"CertificateRevocation"=dword:00000000
"DisableCachingOfSSLPages"=dword:00000000
"IE5_UA_Backup_Flag"="5.0"
"PrivacyAdvanced"=dword:00000001
"SecureProtocols"=dword:000008a0
"User Agent"="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Win32)"
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"EnableAutodial"=dword:00000000
"NoNetAutodial"=dword:00000000
"EnableHTTP1_1"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHTTP1.1"=dword:00000001
"ShowPunycode"=dword:00000000
"EnablePunycode"=dword:00000001
"UrlEncoding"=dword:00000000
"DisableIDNPrompt"=dword:00000000
"EnableNegotiate"=dword:00000001
"WarnonBadCertRecving"=dword:00000001
"WarnonZoneCrossing"=dword:00000000
"WarnOnPostRedirect"=dword:00000001
"ZonesSecurityUpgrade"=hex:f6,3a,c7,0d,32,65,d8,01
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyOverride"="<local>"
"ProxyServer"="proxy.proxydelaempresa.net:8080"
```

Lo que yo digo es que lo hace mi compañero edita esta parte de windows pero es como si solo se editara sin darle a save:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

podrían usar el siguiente código:

```
Reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /f /v "AutoDetect" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" # Autodetección de proxy (0 o 1 para descativar o activar respectivamente)

Reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyEnable" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f # Activación de Proxy (0 o 1 para desactivar o activar respectivamente)


Reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyServer" /t REG_SZ /d "Servidor_proxy:Puerto" /f # Ingreso de Servidor Proxy y puerto
```

Comment: me pasa lo mismo que con el mio, en las configuraciones se ve el cambio pero es como si no se aplicara, hasta que el usuario no va y el mismo le da clic en guardar en el apartado de proxy (que es precisamente lo que quiero evitar) el cambio no se aplica